# Disable Chromium Ctrl+T, Ctrl+N, Ctrl+W, Alt+F4, etc on Linux in kiosk mode?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, raspberry-pi, chromium, raspbian

Is there a way to disable Chormium's shortcut keys in Linux?  I've tried the `--app` and `--kiosk` flags but they don't disable the shortcuts, you can still create a new (though unusable) tab with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and can create a new (fully functional) window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.  Also, Chromium appears to do it's own check for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> because even though I have it disabled in the window manager it will close Chromium.  How do I disable all the shortcuts within Chromium?  Window manager is matchbox, started with xorg + nodm (the default lightdm+openbox system didn't allow me to auto-restart the session or get rid of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

This is for an embedded system using node.js in the background to handle hardware io, but it will need a network connection to function so I want to ensure users are locked out of the browsers (the various <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>* shortcuts have already been removed, Chromium is all that remains in making it a real kiosk system).  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> isn't a major concern (though it would be really nice to get rid of) because when Chromium crashes nodm will automatically restart it and it handles the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> somewhat reasonably (black screen, flashing white, then it's back up - it's not a security concern just a severely ugly "feature" people might stumble accross).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think chromium has an inbuilt interface for disabling os keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, but what you could do is intercept those key-presses with javascript and that should be enough to stop the key-presses from working.

To enable such a script on all your pages, you'd need something like greasemonkey, which chromium has a support for out of the box, you can read about it [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts).

Comment: Disabling via script isn't enough (browsers have hotkeys for context menus with things like ctrl+right-click, the script doesn't stop events during page load, etc) - I ended up going with a custom build of midori.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Keyboard Shortcuts - Chromium extensions